# How to use implode function manualy?

Tags: php

My array contain date `$a1[0]` day `$a1[1]` month `$a1[2]` year I want the result as year/day/month give me one solution.

Below is my code

```
<?php
  $a1 = array("01","10","2012");
  $result = implode("/",$a1);
  print $result;
?>
```

This will print `01/10/2012` but I want this result `2012/01/10`. How can I take the array manualy using implode function?

How can I take year first day second and month third?

Comment: give me another solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use implode alone for that matter, if you are having exactly this pattern (elements order are inverted) the use this code (YYYY/MM/DD):

```
$a1 = array("01", "10", "2012");
$result = implode("/", array_reverse($a1));
print $result;
```

Else use a regex (YYYY/MM/DD):

```
$a1 = array("01", "10", "2012");
$result = preg_replace('/(\d{2})\/(\d{2})\/(\d{4})/', '$3/$2/$1', implode("/", $a1));
print $result;
```

If you need the format of (YYYY/DD/MM) then use this one:

```
$a1 = array("01", "10", "2012");
$result = preg_replace('/(\d{2})\/(\d{2})\/(\d{4})/', '$3/$1/$2', implode("/", $a1));
print $result;
```

Comment: then it will print 2012/10/01 actualy i want 2012/10/01 this result

Answer (score 1):

You can use `array_reverse` like this:

```
$result = implode("/", array_reverse($a1));
```

This will create a new array in the reverse order.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [mktime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mktime.php) function. If you have a $timestamp, you can format is as you like with the date function:

```
$timestamp = mktime(0, 0, 0, $a1[1], $a1[0], $a1[2]);
echo date('y/m/d', $timestamp);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a loop (manual implode):

```
$a1 = array("01","10","2012");
$a1_length = sizeof($a1);
$date = '';
for ($i = $a1_length; $i > 0; $i--) {
    $date .= $a1[$i] . '/';
}
$date = rtrim($date, '/');

echo $date;
```